# Yii issue retrieving relational data

Tags: activerecord, yii, relational-database, relation

I'm create a new table(s) in my Yii application thats going to be used as a relational table, just storing IDs, it's really simple, but i cannot manage to actually get any information passed through from the model, even though the IDs match. Can anyone see where i'm going wrong?

User Model (has many relations, but i've just included the one im having a problem with)

```
public function relations() {
        return array(
            'onsiteGroup' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'EventAttendeesGroups', 'user_id'),
        );
    }
```

EventAttendeeGroups Model

```
class EventAttendeesGroups extends CActiveRecord
{

    public function tableName()
    {
        return '{{event_attendees_groups}}';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('user_id, group_id', 'required'),
            array('user_id, group_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('user_id, group_id', 'safe'),
            array('id, user_id, group_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
                    'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
                    'onsiteGroupName' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'EventAttendeesGroupName', 'group_id'),
        );
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'user_id' => 'User',
            'group_id' => 'Group',
        );
    }

    public function search()
    {
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id);
        $criteria->compare('group_id',$this->group_id);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
}
```

My Data is correct, the user id exists in the user table and in the EventAttendeeGroups table, yet if try the following in the user view gridview table, i get 'Not Set'

```
array(
            'name' => 'group_id',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => $model->onsiteGroup->group_id,
        ),
```

Can anyone see where i'm going wrong???

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error? What is it outputting? Are you trying to render CGridView or what, and if yes is it formed?

One thought, are you sure

```
$model->onsiteGroup->group_id
```

is the object name and not

```
$model->onsiteGroupName->group_id
```

Just a thought.